# What CMS/theme/template/framework does this website use?

Tags: web-development, cms, framework, wordpress

see https://www.example.com/

If it is using WordPress, what theme/plugin does it use? If not, what CMS/framework/template is it built on?

Thanks!

Comment: Install [Wappalyzer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg?hl=en) in your browser for a preflight of info. Wappalyzer says https://elementor.com/. But it actually doesn't look much like WordPress under the hood. Looks more like a static site. Not much to tell from their https://www.sociablelabs.com/css/custom.css and https://www.sociablelabs.com/js/app_original.js.

Comment: I don't think asking for what program do others use is a valid question for this site.

Answer (score 1):

This website does not use WordPress - it doesn't load any resource with a WP-related name, nor it have any JS or CSS class name relationship (except for `.elementor-*` CSS classes on some elements in the homepage).

Looking at the bundled JS file, I can say that the page uses, for sure:

- Bootstrap
- jQuery

It seems that this website is not based on any of the most-known CMSs, if on any.

Comment: The home page and some pages on the home page can be built manually. But I can hardly think the numerous inner pages are also built manually. They must be dynamic pages which are built with some CMS.